# Tilting/twisting/rolling outwards

Tags: modeling

English is not my native language and I have been searching with all the words I can come up with without finding what I need. I am certain it is lots of tutorials out there but I can not find them.

What I am looking for is a way to twist or turn or tilt a ring outwards so the spikes on the ring follow the movement.

Right now, the blue and the pink circles shown on the image are the same size. I like to make the pink ring larger and that way make the spikes tilt out/down. I cut out a part of the image to show how I like the spikes to turn. Thats the green arrows.

I appresiate help to find the right word to search by or, even better, an explanation on how to do this.

Thank you,

EDIT: I do not need to animate this. It is a one time thing. Ofcourse I can do it by turning each spike seperatly by hand but I thought there might be an easier, or at least not so time consuming, way to do it.

[image]

Comment: if i were you i would try solving this via a custom rig or shape keys. a geometry nodes setup could be complicated.

Comment: The way that you're talking about this, and drawing it, sounds like you're thinking about it the same way that a mesh deform works, and that's what I'd recommend looking for.  (As always, there are a billion solutions to the problem-- that just happens to be the one that should already meet your intuitions.)

Answer (score 1):

It would have helped a lot, if you would have provided a blend file or more information how you did this "thing".
Assuming you have done it cleverly, then you used an array modifier with an empty.
If you then just rotate in edit mode, you can do this:

[image]

Comment: No, Unfortunatly I am not that smart. I am still a newbie and have not learned about arrays...yet. I will look into thaat noww tho. Thank you for the idea.